# Constant print screen bug/virus in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

Long story short: my computer won't stop taking screenshots, whatever I do.

If I try to copy a text (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, for example), I'd paste it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and the content in the clipboard would already be a screenshot of the instant I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. And that is not only with the keyboard shortcuts, that also happens if I right-click copy and paste.

If I keep pressing the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> key, the screen will start to blink darker and save tons of screenshots in the `~/Screenshots/` folder, because of the Windows 10 mechanism of automatically saving screenshots in that folder when you press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Screen</kbd>.

The key doesn't seem physically stuck, although I wouldn't doubt it if it was internally stuck. But I fear this is some kind of virus made to spy on what I'm doing, or some software that I installed that went crazy.

I tested closing multiple processes that weren't system related to see if any of them were causing the problem, but I didn't get any consistent results.

Someone knows what this is?

Comment: @Worthwelle it was my keyboard! I was using an external usb keyboard, I tried disabling it, and it stopped taking screenshots. Thanks! Can you make and answer with that so I can accept it?

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer.

Comment: @Worthwelle Actually, it worked for like 10 minutes, and it's back again x.x I'll try the safe mode

Comment: Any luck solving this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to rule out if it's a software you installed is to restart in Safe Mode. That will run Windows without starting applications and services that start on startup.

1. Click the Start button and click the Settings gear.
2. Click *Update & Security*, then *Recovery*.
3. Under *Advanced Startup*, select *Restart Now*.
4. Your PC will restart and show the *Choose an Option* screen. Select *Troubleshoot* → *Advanced Options* → *Startup Settings* → *Restart*.
5. After your PC restarts, select 4 or <kbd>F4</kbd> to start your PC in Safe Mode.

You can also try unplugging your keyboard and using the onscreen keyboard to see if it still does it there.

1. Click the Start button and click the Settings gear.
2. Click *Ease of Access*.
3. Click *Keyboard*.
4. Set *Use the On-Screen Keyboard* to *On*.
5. Unplug your physical keyboard and replicate the steps that caused the issue before.